# convert a string type(MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM) to date format in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a string in format 05/26/2021 11:31:56 AM for mat and I want to convert it to a date format like 05-26-2021 in pyspark.

I have tried below things but its converting the column type to date but making the values null.

```
df = df.withColumn("columnname", F.to_date(df["columnname"], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

another one which I have tried is

```
df = df.withColumn("columnname", df["columnname"].cast(DateType()))
```

I have also tried the below method

```
df = df.withColumn(column.lower(), F.to_date(F.col(column.lower())).alias(column).cast("date"))
```

but in every method I was able to convert the column type to date but it makes the values null.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: use `to_date(df['col'], 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')`

Comment: Hey @mck I tried the one which you are suggesting, I am facing the same problem, it changes the column datatype but makes the data null.

Comment: is the original data null? you might have overwritten it in your code

Comment: No, the original data contains string type and I am only converting into Date format, I am not doing any other transformation in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create data frame like below
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("Test", "05/26/2021 11:31:56 AM")], 
("user_name", "login_date"))

# Import functions
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# Create data framew with new column new_date with data in desired format
df1 = df.withColumn("new_date", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("login_date",'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'),'yyyy-MM-dd').cast('date'))
```

Comment: Hey this works, I was doing the work around as below                                                           df = df.withColumn(column, F.unix_timestamp(column, "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss aa").cast("double").cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn(column, F.from_utc_timestamp(column, 'Z').cast(DateType()))

Comment: Hey I have accepted your answer , Thanks for the help @user12345, I was only saying that I used to two statements to achieve, what you did in one, I am using your statement in the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The above answer posted by @User12345 works and the below method is also works

```
df = df.withColumn(column, F.unix_timestamp(column, "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss aa").cast("double").cast("timestamp"))
df = df.withColumn(column, F.from_utc_timestamp(column, 'Z').cast(DateType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this
df=data.withColumn("Date",to_date(to_timestamp("Date","M/d/yyyy")))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).